# DefaultServerRenderer2.setProperty error in SSR angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering, nebular

I use [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) with some change in `server.ts`. I added `domino` to define `window` object to prevent some "**window not define**" error on the server side.

This is error log:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined at 
EmulatedEncapsulationServerRenderer2.DefaultServerRenderer2.setProperty 
(/universal/dist/server.js:125246:34) at BaseAnimationRenderer.setProperty 
(/universal/dist/server.js:124312:27) at SafeSubscriber._next 
(/universal/dist/server.js:161724:28) at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub 
(/universal/dist/server.js:27968:16) at SafeSubscriber.next 
(/universal/dist/server.js:27906:22) at Subscriber._next 
(/universal/dist/server.js:27849:26) at Subscriber.next 
(/universal/dist/server.js:27826:18) at TakeWhileSubscriber.nextOrComplete 
(/universal/dist/server.js:37724:25) at TakeWhileSubscriber._next 
(/universal/dist/server.js:37719:14) at TakeWhileSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/universal/dist/server.js:27826:18)
```

from this file:

`angular/platform-server/src/server_renderer.ts` [LINK](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-server/src/server_renderer.ts)

How can I fix this?
The repo is here [angular-universal-nebular-theme](https://github.com/alikarimii/angular-universal-nebular-theme)

Comment: How can we reproduce your issue?

Comment: @yurzui, I linked repo. you can test it.https://github.com/alikarimii/angular-universal-nebular-theme

Comment: Which command should I run to see that error? I tried `npm run build:ssr` and `npm run serve:ssr`. All of them work swimmingly

Comment: @yurzui your command is correct. but when "serve:ssr" go to route "http://localhost:4000/sample"

Comment: This code causes that error https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/50e73b9cee3f48b16a9d007011235213a1bc013e/src/framework/theme/components/layout/layout.component.ts#L459 We can't set property on document through renderer. It only applies elements. We can use `this.document.dir = direction` instead.